# Spark Streaming Job is running very slow

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, spark-streaming

[image][image]I am running a spark streaming job in my local and it is taking approximately 4 to 5 min for one batch. Can someone suggest what could be the issue with the bellow code?

```
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession
from pyspark.sql.types import StructType, StructField, StringType, FloatType, TimestampType
from pyspark.sql.functions import avg, window, from_json, from_unixtime, unix_timestamp
import uuid

schema = StructType([
    StructField("source", StringType(), True),
    StructField("temperature", FloatType(), True),
    StructField("time", StringType(), True)
])

spark = SparkSession \
    .builder.master("local[8]") \
    .appName("poc-app") \
    .getOrCreate()

spark.conf.set("spark.sql.shuffle.partitions", 5)    

df1 = spark \
    .readStream \
    .format("kafka") \
    .option("kafka.bootstrap.servers", "localhost:9092") \
    .option("subscribe", "poc") \
    .load() \
    .selectExpr("CAST(value AS STRING)")

df2 = df1.select(from_json("value", schema).alias(
    "sensors")).select("sensors.*")

df3=df2.select(df2.source,df2.temperature,from_unixtime(unix_timestamp(df2.time, 'yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss')).alias('time'))
df4 = df3.groupBy(window(df3.time, "2 minutes","1 minutes"), df3.source).count()

query1 = df4.writeStream \
.outputMode("complete") \
.format("console") \
.option("checkpointLocation", "/tmp/temporary-" + str(uuid.uuid4())) \
.start() 

query1.awaitTermination()
```

Comment: What the size of JSONs coming from your Kafka and how many events per minute/second? How many executors was lauched on application and how many resources was allocated for? While the application is running, which actons are taking the most part of the time?

Comment: I am publishing the below message to kafka every second. "{"temperature":45,"time":"2019-04-17 12:53:02","source":"1010101"}". I am running this program in my local (8GB RAM) so just using default settings.

Comment: Maybe a first thing to do is increase the application resources. Try to pass on your pyspark/spark-submit program the `--driver-memory 2g` option. It will give 2g to driver process and maybe will help something. Look at Spark UI and tell us what job was taking long time.

Comment: I have submitted the pyspark job with 2g and still taking more time. I have attached the Job details.

Comment: Try the answer according wih @thePurplePython. This variable need to be set up if you are working with SparkSQL

Comment: Thanks @Igor Uchôa

Answer (score 4, accepted):

with mini-batch streaming you usually want to reduce the # of output partitions ... since you are doing some aggregation (wide transformation) every time you persist it will default to 200 partitions to disk because of

```
spark.conf.get("spark.sql.shuffle.partitions")
```

try lowering this config to a smaller output partition and place it at the beginning of your code so when the aggregation is performed it outputs 5 partitions to disk

```
spark.conf.set("spark.sql.shuffle.partitions", 5)
```

you can also get a feel by looking at the # of files in the output write stream directory as well as identifying the # of partitions in your aggregated df

```
df3.rdd.getNumPartitions()
```

btw since you are using a local mode for testing try setting to local[8] instead of local[4] so it increases the parallelism on your cpu cores (i assume you have 4)

Comment: thanks alot!!. After making the changes the batches are running very fast. I have updated the code. Please suggest on how to check 5 consecutive  temperature values exceed the given range (<30 && >40)  in a given window

Comment: do you have any idea how to check 5 consecutive temperature values exceeds threshold limit?

Comment: did you try adding a WHERE clause in your logic?